# IntelliJ Call Hierarchy shows only calls from within current class

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ 2021.2.1 (Community Edition).

When trying to see call hierarchy of a method (Ctrl + Option + H on mac), I get only the callers from the same class as the method I'm inspecting. In other words, calls to non-private methods that are done from another class are not displayed in the hierarchy.

I made sure that in the Scope select box, "All" is selected, but still I see only calls from current class.
I tried to change the scope to "This class" and then back to "All" or "Production", but this made no changes.

How can I fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: Use Cmb+B to show callers (Go to declaration or usages).

Comment: cmd+b is working fine, but I need the call hierarchy view, because it's a method called by many other methods, and I want to see the entire hierarchy of each call.

Comment: It looks like this issue, but it should actually be fixed in 2021.2.1: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-275145

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug:  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-275145.
It should be fixed in 2021.2.1.